# sencha android packaging packager.json (on windows)

Tags: android, windows, extjs, cmd, packaging

getting [ERR] java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING)

Seems like a JOSN parsing error, but all tips i found aren't working. The project is perfectly builded, my packager.json looks like that:

```
{
   "applicationName":"firstapp",
   "applicationId":"com.parcello.firstapp",
   "versionString":"1.0",
   "iconName:":"resources\icons\Icon.png",
   "inputPath":"\",
   "outputPath":"C:\Users\mitch\Desktop\touch-2.3.0\firstapp\and\",
   "configuration":"Debug",
   "platform":"Android",
   "deviceType":"Universal",
   "certificatePath":"C:\Users\mitch\Desktop\touch-2.3.0\firstapp\release.keystore",
   "certificateAlias":"firstapp",
   "sdkPath":"C:\Users\mitch\android-sdks",
   "orientations": [
       "portrait",
       "landscapeLeft",
       "landscapeRight",
       "portraitUpsideDown"
   ]
}
```

and the complete error in my win command is:

> [ERR] java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was
>   STRING at line 9 column 26
>        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:176)
>        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:791)
>        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:757)
>        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:706)
>        at com.sencha.util.JsonUtil$ThreadSafeGson.fromJson(JsonUtil.java:228)
>        at com.sencha.util.JsonUtil.fromJson(JsonUtil.java:128)
>        at com.sencha.tools.pkg.Model$Package.load(Model.java:651)
>        at com.sencha.tools.pkg.LocalRepository.verifyPackage(LocalRepository.java:548)
>        at com.sencha.tools.pkg.LocalRepository.addPackage(LocalRepository.java:351)
>        at com.sencha.command.pkg.AddCommand.execute(AddCommand.java:28)

Any ideas, because of that the command:

```
sencha app build native
```

isn't running as well.

It's touch 2.3.0 with : http://docs-devel.sencha.com/touch/2.3.0/#!/guide/getting_started

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSON you provided is invalid as you have not escaped the backslash '\' characters.

Once '\' is changed to  '\' the JSON is valid:

```
{
   "applicationName":"firstapp",
   "applicationId":"com.parcello.firstapp",
   "versionString":"1.0",
   "iconName:":"resources\\icons\\Icon.png",
   "inputPath":"\\",
   "outputPath":"C:\\Users\\mitch\\Desktop\\touch-2.3.0\\firstapp\\and\\",
   "configuration":"Debug",
   "platform":"Android",
   "deviceType":"Universal",
   "certificatePath":"C:\\Users\\mitch\\Desktop\\touch-2.3.0\\firstapp\\release.keystore",
   "certificateAlias":"firstapp",
   "sdkPath":"C:\\Users\\mitch\\android-sdks",
   "orientations": [
       "portrait",
       "landscapeLeft",
       "landscapeRight",
       "portraitUpsideDown"
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this 
change from '\'  to '/' in your path

"sdkPath":"D:/path_to_your_adt/adt-bundle/sdk/tools",

:-)